# How long does it take to give decision on revised manuscript?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review

My research field is pure mathematics. I received a major revision of one of my articles. I sent the revised version, and the editor said he would let us know the decision after referee's recommendation. Since then it has been 2 months, but yet to receive the decision.

- How long does it take to give a decision after revision?
- Should I contact the editor to know about the update, if any?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a)

Comment: Is the journal submission system showing the revised is *under review*? Major revision ought to go through review again (by the reviewers).

Comment: @semmyk-research, there is no way to track the online status in the journal. I sent the revised version through email to editor. The editor said they will send it to the reviewer and let me know the final decision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I contact the editor to know about the update ...

You may *gently nudge* the editor via the journal system. However, 60 days isn't too long for a **major revision**. It all depends on the discipline and journal process: though there are other factors.

Before contacting the editor, you might want to consider the following

- [Journal Paper Review (Computer Science) taking so long (*after submitting revised manuscript*)? How to proceed?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194951/journal-paper-review-computer-science-taking-so-long-how-to-proceed)
- [Should I withdraw my paper because review is taking too long?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178056/should-i-withdraw-my-paper-because-review-is-taking-too-long)

> How long does it take to give a decision after revision?

The timeframe varies from journal to journal and on various factors. Some journals might give median times: [Physical Review editor was given here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/133509/life-cycle-for-physical-review-letters). You might need to check with the journal.

Answer (score 1):

I would do nothing at this stage.

When you submit a revision, the editor will send it back out to the original reviewers (assuming they agree). That in itself will take a bit of time - sometimes the editor doesn't have time to do it immediately, and people could take time to agree.

Then, typically I would expect to be allowed at least 2 months (perhaps 3) to check a major revision. And it would probably take this long: when I get asked to do this, I will accept but I will almost always have other reviewing tasks that I accepted earlier and are more pressing. This is different from checking a minor revision, which is often straightforward enough that it can jump the queue without unduly delaying other things.

For context, I have currently been waiting just over two months to hear back about a *minor* revision (in pure math). People can be busy, especially at this time of year. I am just going to carry on waiting for the time being.

Comment: Thank you so much. I agreed